# dd with multiple output to script

Tags: bash, dd

I want to make multiple copies of a file and I am able to do it like this...

```
dd if=~/learndir/source.txt | tee >(dd of=~/learndir/un.txt) | tee >(dd of=~/learndir/deux.txt) | tee >(dd of=~/learndir/trois.txt) | tee >(dd of=~/learndir/quatre.txt) | dd of=~/learndir/cinque.txt
```

my problem is that this works in the terminal but not in a script.  Here is a script with the same syntax that I try to execute...

```
#!/bin/sh

dd if=~/learndir/source.txt | tee >(dd of=~/learndir/un.txt) | tee
>(dd of=~/learndir/deux.txt) | tee >(dd of=~/learndir/trois.txt) | tee >(dd of=~/learndir/quatre.txt) | dd of=~/learndir/cinque.txt
```

and I get the following error...

```
~$ sh duplicate5.sh
> duplicate5.sh: 2: duplicate5.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I don't understand why it works at my dollar prompt but not in a script.

Comment: Your shell is `/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` behaves differently from `/bin/sh`.  Use `#!/bin/bash` in the script and it should be OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shell is `/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` behaves differently from `/bin/sh`.  Use `#!/bin/bash` in the script and it should be OK.  Also, the script has a bad line-break in it.

Incidentally, a single copy of `tee` can write to multiple files in a single invocation:

```
dd if=~/learndir/source.txt |
tee >(dd of=~/learndir/un.txt) \
    >(dd of=~/learndir/deux.txt) \
    >(dd of=~/learndir/trois.txt) \
    >(dd of=~/learndir/quatre.txt) |
dd of=~/learndir/cinque.txt
```

But using `dd` and [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) seems superfluous here:

```
cat ~/learndir/source.txt |
tee ~/learndir/un.txt ~/learndir/deux.txt ~/learndir/trois.txt ~/learndir/quatre.txt \
    > ~/learndir/cinque.txt
```

Or even:

```
tee < ~/learndir/source.txt \
    ~/learndir/un.txt ~/learndir/deux.txt ~/learndir/trois.txt ~/learndir/quatre.txt \
    > ~/learndir/cinque.txt
```

The I/O redirections can appear in an arbitrary order in this script, so this also works:

```
tee < ~/learndir/source.txt > ~/learndir/cinque.txt \
    ~/learndir/un.txt ~/learndir/deux.txt ~/learndir/trois.txt ~/learndir/quatre.txt
```

Or:

```
tee ~/learndir/un.txt ~/learndir/deux.txt ~/learndir/trois.txt ~/learndir/quatre.txt \
    < ~/learndir/source.txt > ~/learndir/cinque.txt
```

Etc.

Comment: Johnathan, Thanks for the quick answer.